# How to compare Color object and get closest Color in an Color[]?

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, win-universal-app

Let's say I have an array with colors (with the whole color spectrum, from red to red.). A shorter version would look like this:

```
public Color[] ColorArray = new Color[360] { Color.FromArgb(255, 245, 244, 242), Color.FromArgb(255, 245, 244, 240), Color.FromArgb(255, 245, 244, 238) }
```

Now if I have a seperate

```
Color object (Color c = Color.FromArgb(255, 14, 4, 5))
```

How can I get the value in the Array that is the closest to the selected color? And is this even possible?

Comment: Its possible, you just need to write a custom comparer... How do you determine which is closer to white though out of `(255,0,255)` and `(0, 255, 255)`?

Comment: You will need to define what 'closer' means. Usually this is obvious but with colours it may be a good idea to do some extra thinking and testing. A direct approach would simply measure the distance by adding the differences of the 3 RGB channels; but maybe you'd rather gauge the measurement by giving more weight to the hue than the brightness and the saturation..? All these values are directly accessible in the Color class..

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Color distance is not a precisely defined thing. So here are **three** methods to measure it:

- One method that checks **only the hues** of the colors, ignoring both saturation and brightness
- One that only measures the direct distance in **RGB** space
- And one that **weighs** hue, saturation and brightness in some way.

Obviously you may want to change the magic numbers in the 3rd measurement:  hue is in 0-360, brightness and saturation are in 0-1, so with these numbers hue weighs about 3.6 times stronger than saturation and brightness..

**Update**:  The original solution I posted contained several errors:

- The Linq I used didn't find the closest but the closestFromBelow; this meant a 50% chance of being off by one.
- In some places I used the `color.GetBrightness()` method. This is, to put it mildly, totally useless. To wit: `Blue` and `Yellow` have the  same value of `0.5`!
- The values for hue go from 0-360, but of course they wrap around! I missed that completely..

I have replaced most of the original answer with corrected code:

These now are the new versions of the methods, each returning the index of the closest match found:

```
// closed match for hues only:
int closestColor1(List<Color> colors, Color target)
{
    var hue1 = target.GetHue();
    var diffs = colors.Select(n => getHueDistance(n.GetHue(), hue1));
    var diffMin = diffs.Min(n => n);
    return diffs.ToList().FindIndex(n => n == diffMin);
}

// closed match in RGB space
int closestColor2(List<Color> colors, Color target)
{
    var colorDiffs = colors.Select(n => ColorDiff(n, target)).Min(n =>n);
    return colors.FindIndex(n => ColorDiff(n, target) == colorDiffs);
}

// weighed distance using hue, saturation and brightness
int closestColor3(List<Color> colors, Color target)
{
    float hue1 = target.GetHue();
    var num1 = ColorNum(target);
    var diffs = colors.Select(n => Math.Abs(ColorNum(n) - num1) + 
                                   getHueDistance(n.GetHue(), hue1) );
    var diffMin = diffs.Min(x => x);
    return diffs.ToList().FindIndex(n => n == diffMin);
}
```

A few helper functions:

```
 // color brightness as perceived:
float getBrightness(Color c)  
    { return (c.R * 0.299f + c.G * 0.587f + c.B *0.114f) / 256f;}

// distance between two hues:
float getHueDistance(float hue1, float hue2)
{ 
    float d = Math.Abs(hue1 - hue2); return d > 180 ? 360 - d : d; }

//  weighed only by saturation and brightness (from my trackbars)
float ColorNum(Color c) { return c.GetSaturation() * factorSat + 
                                      getBrightness(c) * factorBri; }

// distance in RGB space
int ColorDiff(Color c1, Color c2) 
      { return  (int ) Math.Sqrt((c1.R - c2.R) * (c1.R - c2.R) 
                               + (c1.G - c2.G) * (c1.G - c2.G)
                               + (c1.B - c2.B) * (c1.B - c2.B)); }
```

Here is the handy little helper I used for the screenshot texts:

```
Brush tBrush(Color c) { 
      return getBrightness(c) < 0.5 ? Brushes.White : Brushes.Black; }
```

I have updated the screenshot to display not only 13 colors but also a number of mostly reddish colors for testing; all colors are shown with their values for hue, saturation and brightness. The last three numbers are the results of the three methods.

As you can see, the simple distance method is quite misleading hue-wise for bright and non-saturated colors: The last color (Ivory) is in fact a bright and pale yellow!

The third method which gauges all color properties is best imo. You should play around with the gauging numbers, though!

In the end it really depends on what you want to achieve; if, as it seems, you only care about the hues of the colors, simply go for the first method! You can call it, using your array like this:

```
int indexInArray = closestColor1(clist.ToList(), someColor);
```

For more on [color distances see Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_difference)!

[image: color distances]

```
// the colors I used:
// your array
Color[] clist = new Color[13];
clist[0] = Color.Blue;
clist[1] = Color.BlueViolet;
clist[2] = Color.Magenta;
clist[3] = Color.Purple;
clist[4] = Color.Red;
clist[5] = Color.Tomato;
clist[6] = Color.Orange;
clist[7] = Color.Yellow;
clist[8] = Color.YellowGreen;
clist[9] = Color.Green;
clist[10] = Color.SpringGreen;
clist[11] = Color.Cyan;
clist[12] = Color.Ivory;

// and a list of color to test:
List<Color> targets = new List<Color>();
targets.Add(Color.Pink);
targets.Add(Color.OrangeRed);
targets.Add(Color.LightPink);
targets.Add(Color.DarkSalmon);
targets.Add(Color.LightCoral);
targets.Add(Color.DarkRed);
targets.Add(Color.IndianRed);
targets.Add(Color.LavenderBlush);
targets.Add(Color.Lavender);
```

Comment: So I have a colorwheel with all colors, and I get a RGB value. Now I want to place the picker on the color that has the closest match.

So if the RGB value is red-ish it should be in the red-ish part of the colorwheel.

Comment: If you care __only__ about the hue of the color, especially if your color list is all saturated, choose the __1st__ method!

Comment: The weight of the hue needs to *diminish* as the lightness approaches 0 or 1. IOW, I can have two very close, very bright (or very dark colors), but their hues could be off by 180.

Comment: Interesting concept that probably rather often makes a lot of sense. The second method (direct distance in RGB space) basically does something similar, though..

Comment: The first method is working, but mixes the red and the white, if my list is having the white first, all reds outputs white, if the red is first in the list, all whites read red...

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
    static void Main()
    {
        Color[] ColorArray =
        {
            Color.FromArgb(255, 245, 244, 242), 
            Color.FromArgb(255, 245, 244, 240),
            Color.FromArgb(255, 245, 244, 238)
        };

        var closest = GetClosestColor(ColorArray, Color.FromArgb(255, 245, 244, 241));
        Console.WriteLine(closest);
    }

    private static Color GetClosestColor(Color[] colorArray, Color baseColor)
    {
        var colors = colorArray.Select(x => new {Value = x, Diff = GetDiff(x, baseColor)}).ToList();
        var min = colors.Min(x => x.Diff);
        return colors.Find(x => x.Diff == min).Value;
    }

    private static int GetDiff(Color color, Color baseColor)
    {
        int a = color.A - baseColor.A,
            r = color.R - baseColor.R,
            g = color.G - baseColor.G,
            b = color.B - baseColor.B;
        return a*a + r*r + g*g + b*b;
    }
```

here I interpret `closest` as Euclidean distance in ARGB space