# How to check if a HSL color's hue is in given range?

Tags: c#, hsl

I'm using the HSL colour space.
The Hue factor is from 0 to 360 degrees, and going from zero to 360 means to go a full circle around on the colour circle. So 0 is close to 360 (or they are the same). This implies that to do some range checking one would need the modulo function.

I need to check if value `HueX` is within distance `RangeH` of `Hue`:
So if `Hue = 20` and `RangeH = 50` then if `HueX = 350` then the value of `350` is in range.

I've been trying a few combinations of math but not with the results I was hoping for, as I think this could be written as a boolean function one liner.

Comment: I have no clue what you need. Maybe you can correct a few typos in your post and see where this leads? Is Heu the same as Hue?

Comment: I mend Hue, HSL is a cylindric color space model. Where H,..Hue stands for the color, S for saturation (color vs gray), and L for how luminous, or how light a color is.

Comment: You may want to have a look at [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27374550/how-to-compare-color-object-and-get-closest-color-in-an-color/27375621#27375621); espcially the line where: `float d = Math.Abs(hue1 - hue2); return d > 180 ? 360 - d : d; }`

Answer (score 2):

I use this method to work with Hue values:

```
public static double HueDifference(double hue1, double hue2)
{
    return Math.Min(Math.Abs(hue1 - hue2), 360 - Math.Abs(hue1- hue2));
}
```

Then you can check if the value is within the given range like this:

```
if (HueDifference(HueX, Hue) <= RangeH)
    // ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Well based upon Taw4, i wrote a function that included the HSL hue math.
Its not the onliner check, which i think exists using a mod calculation.
And well i do was looking for that one, but i dont remember it.
I rewrote the logic of the link from Taw4 a bit.

I wrote this as part of my function that checks if an 
RGB color is within an HSL range, the S and L factors are quite easy, but i the H got me troubled. I just post the whole thing here, just in case someone needs it.

```
        private Boolean RGBInHSLRange
          (int r, int g, int b,
           int h,int s,int l,
           int RH, int RS, int RL)   
    {   // r,g,b colors
        // h,s,l colors
        // ranges for HSL in RH,RS,RL

        // note color math is usually done in floats not integers
        // if you need floats do a float conversion instead of int
        // for me int ewas enough 
        Color myColor = Color.FromArgb(r, g, b);
        int HSLhue = (int)myColor.GetHue(); 
        int HSLsat = (int)(myColor.GetSaturation() * 100);
        int HSLlight = (int)(myColor.GetBrightness() * 100);


        if (( HSLlight < h -RL) ^ ( HSLlight > h +RL)) return false;
        if (( HSLsat < s - RS) ^ ( HSLsat > s + RS)) return false;

        int distance = Math.Abs(h - HSLhue);
        if (distance > 180) distance = 360 - distance;
        if (distance > RH) return false;
        return true;           
    }
```