# How to use rgb difference between two colors in C# in order to find the closest match?

Tags: c#, colors, hex, rgb

I have a code that gets the closest color based on RGB difference, but with dark colors like dark blue, it returns black instead of "dark blue". Can u guys help me finding out what's happening?

This is the code that calculates RGB difference between two colors:

```
int ColorDiff(Color c1, Color c2)
{
    return (int)Math.Sqrt((c1.R - c2.R) * (c1.R - c2.R)
                        + (c1.G - c2.G) * (c1.G - c2.G)
                        + (c1.B - c2.B) * (c1.B - c2.B));
}
```

This code gets the closest color on the list (the one that has less difference between RGB):

```
int encontrarCor(List<Color> colors, Color target)
{
    var colorDiffs = colors.Select(n => ColorDiff(n, target)).Min(n => n);
    return colors.FindIndex(n => ColorDiff(n, target) == colorDiffs);
}
```

What I think is happening is that, as you can see in the first code, it does: (c1.R - c2.R) * (c1.R - c2.R), so if one of these substrates is equal to 0, the whole product is gonna be 0, so returns black, cause RGB code of black is 0,0,0.

I've tried to make myself as clear as possible, sorry if is a little bit confused.

Comment: You need to manually calculate the *distance* between these colors - perhaps, it is just really closer to black than to dark blue. If you want us to hepl you, then you need to provide the following information: RGB of your "dark blue" standard; RGB example of color which results into black when you expect it to result into dark blue.

Comment: your description doesn't match the code......   if one of those color diffs = 0, then the difference is 0 for that channel, which is correct, there is no difference.   That 0 isn't use for a color at all.   It then weirdly does it all again so it can find the index of the color with the lowest difference

Comment: *"so if one of these substrates is equal to 0, the whole product is gonna be 0"* - wrong. You are not using the product of color components' distances, you sum them up. If one of them calculates to zero, then sum can still be non-zero.

Comment: some tips :-  If you want to get the closest match it can be slightly less darker or slightly more darker than the color to match  . In this case you will get two options.  Second You can also use hex converter and can use hexadecimal arithmetic to get more accurate result

Comment: You may find [this dicussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27374550/how-to-compare-color-object-and-get-closest-color-in-an-color/27375621?s=1|1.0579#27375621) of interest - Btw, the root won't make much of a difference, a simple square or even abs is good enough.. weighing is more important!

Answer (score 0):

I don't get the point of the square root and multiplications, but the differences should be positive:

```
int RGBdiff(Color c1, Color c2)
{
    return Math.Abs(c1.R - c2.R) + Math.Abs(c1.G - c2.G) + Math.Abs(c1.B - c2.B);
}

Color ClosestColor(Color target, IEnumerable<Color> colors)
{
    return colors.Min(c => Tuple.Create(RGBdiff(c, targert), c)).Item2;
}
```

Note that more than one color can have the same difference.