# Remove all tones of a color from a bitmap

Tags: c#, image, image-processing, c#-4.0, ocr

Hello I am trying to eliminate all the orange tones of an image saved in a bitmap, I need to do OCR in the image with tesseract and the orange color of the scanned document seems to hinder the process producing errors in the text, I have tried removing the orange color I with photoshop, making the OCR and works perfectly, the main problem is that the pixels are not all of the same color, they are orange but in different shades

```
Bitmap modificar = new Bitmap("imagenamodificar.png");
        for (int ycount2 = 0; ycount2 < modificar.Height; ycount2++)
        {
            for (int xcount2 = 0; xcount2 < modificar.Width; xcount2++)
            {
                if (modificar.GetPixel(xcount2, ycount2) == Color.Orange)
                {
                    modificar.SetPixel(xcount2, ycount2, Color.White);
                }
            }
        }
```

This code does absolutely nothing, the image remains identical.

Then it occurs to me to compare with the pixel (0,0) since it is always the color I want to eliminate.

```
Bitmap modificar = new Bitmap("imagenamodificar.png");
        for (int ycount2 = 0; ycount2 < modificar.Height; ycount2++)
        {
            for (int xcount2 = 1; xcount2 < modificar.Width; xcount2++)
            {
                if (modificar.GetPixel(xcount2, ycount2) == modificar.GetPixel(0,0))
                {
                    modificar.SetPixel(xcount2, ycount2, Color.White);
                }
            }
        }
```

But the problem is that it only removes a small part, orange pixels remain because as I mentioned before, not all orange tones are the same, can someone think of something?

Comment: 1) named colors can only be compared to getpixel colors by toARGB. b) something like getHue allows matching hue with an epsilon. c) using lockbits will allow speed. d) so does a color matrix. e)See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27374550/how-to-compare-color-object-and-get-closest-color-in-an-color/27375621#27375621) for examples of color matching.

Comment: @TaW 
I am still something new programming and I can not understand what the code does in the example could you help me?

Comment: @Cristian it appears to convert the colour to HSB colour space in order to compare the hue.

Comment: It has __3 different__ ways to compare colors.  You should try each to see which coomes closest to your needs. Two of the functions use the Color.GetHue function which is built-in. But the hue of orange is the same as the hue of many browns; so if you want to catch only a range of orange hues the 3rd function (`closestColor3` or actually just `ColorNum`) would be best.. -

Comment: Don't worry about the code at the end; it just creates the color chart.. - The functions will sort a list by closeness to a target color. Using just the `ColorNum` functi9on will give you a distance number you can use directly to compare to an epsilon you define..

Comment: @taw i've updated my example i didn't understand the constants he was using. so i couldn't compare the results. it would be interesting to see difference on a color wheel though

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here are some key points to help you along your way

1. Don't use `GetPixel` `SetPixel`, its extremely slow
2. To help with speed its probably best to use `unsafe` with pointer access and call `lockbits` to get a `Pinned Array`
3. You probably want to use a *Threshold* to figure out if a particular pixel color is close to the one you want to remove

A simple color threshold can be calculated by the following (you can also calculate this on Hue)

**Given**

- `threshold` is some `int`
- a source color
- a pixel color

**Threshold**

```
var thresh = threshold * threshold;

// decode the RBG from the image Pointer
var r = ((*p >> 16) & 255) - sR;
var g = ((*p >> 8) & 255) - sG;
var b = ((*p >> 0) & 255) - sB;

// compare it against the threshold
if (r * r + g * g + b * b > thresh)
   continue;
```

> **Note** : The link given in the comments by **TaW** is extremely helpful at figuring out color distance.

Use `lockbits` to get access to the *Scanlines* and *Pin* our memory

[Bitmap.LockBits Method (Rectangle, ImageLockMode, PixelFormat)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ey6h79d(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Locks a Bitmap into system memory.

**Code**

```
private static unsafe void ConvertImage(string fromPath, string toPath, Color source, Color targetColor, double threshold)
{
   var thresh = threshold * threshold;
   var target = targetColor.ToArgb();

   using (var bmp = new Bitmap(fromPath))
   {   
      // lock the array for direct access
      var data = bmp.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height), ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, PixelFormat.Format32bppPArgb);
      // Convert the source to rgb
      int sR = source.R, sG = source.G, sB = source.B;
      // store the max length so we don't have to recalculate it
      var length = (int*)data.Scan0 + bmp.Height * bmp.Width;

      for (var p = (int*)data.Scan0; p < length; p++)           
      {

         // get the rgb Distance
         var r = ((*p >> 16) & 255) - sR;
         var g = ((*p >> 8) & 255) - sG;
         var b = ((*p >> 0) & 255) - sB;

         // compare it against the threshold
         if (r * r + g * g + b * b > thresh)
            continue;
         // poke the target color in
         *p = target;
      }

      // unlock the bitmap
      bmp.UnlockBits(data);
      bmp.Save(toPath);
   }
}
```

**Usage**

```
ConvertImage(@"d:\test.jpg", @"D:\result.bmp", Color.FromArgb(247, 107, 1), Color.Black, 25);
```

> **Note** : i'm using a jpg color wheel so its not as clean as it could be

---

**Original image**

[image]

**Threshold 25**

[image]

**Threshold 75**

[image]

**Threshold 150**

[image]

**Orange Test threshold 75**

[image]

[image]

---

[unsafe (C# Reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/unsafe)

> The unsafe keyword denotes an unsafe context, which is required for
>   any operation involving pointers

[Unsafe Code and Pointers (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/unsafe-code-pointers/index)

> In the common language runtime (CLR), unsafe code is referred to as
>   unverifiable code. Unsafe code in C# is not necessarily dangerous; it
>   is just code whose safety cannot be verified by the CLR. The CLR will
>   therefore only execute unsafe code if it is in a fully trusted
>   assembly. If you use unsafe code, it is your responsibility to ensure
>   that your code does not introduce security risks or pointer errors.

Comment: I've been trying for a few hours to make the code work and trying to understand it and I could not, one thing the whole parameter tresh what is it doing?

Comment: @CristianGerani give me a sec and ill test it and get back to you

Comment: thank you very much and I made it work, 
It works perfect @TheGeneral

Comment: @CristianGerani i update my answer there were a lot of mistakes in the code. so i thought id fix it for future readers