# Capture image from screen and get colors

Tags: c#

I'm making a program which can capture a small area on screen and will run something if there is any color on image that match the target colors. My program run as the following Sequence:

1. Get image from a specific area from screen
2. Save to a folder
3. using `CountPixel` to detect any target_color
   However, after I click the `button5` twice times (not double click), it through an exception at below line :

   b.Save(@"C:\Applications\CaptureImage000.jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);

Exception :

> An unhandled exception of type
>   'System.Runtime.InteropServices.ExternalException' occurred in
>   System.Drawing.dll

Additional information: A generic error occurred in GDI+

**My questions are :**

1. How can i fix this exception ?
2. I want to use another method instead of `CountPixel()` to improve performance, because I just need to detect only one target color to rise event.
3. Step 2 is troublesome. I wonder if i can skip it and use the other way to call: `(@"C:\Applications\CaptureImage000.jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg)` , because using this long string isn't comfortable and result error when im trying to use with `GetPixel`,... or add it into some "value example" code on internet for improvement purpose.

   ```
   private int CountPixels(Bitmap bm, Color target_color)
   {
       // Loop through the pixels.
       int matches = 0;
       for (int y = 0; y < bm.Height; y++)
       {
           for (int x = 0; x < bm.Width; x++)
           {
               if (bm.GetPixel(x, y) == target_color) matches++;
           }
       }
       return matches;
   }
   private Bitmap CapturedImage(int x, int y)
   {
       Bitmap b = new Bitmap(XX, YY);


       Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(b);
       g.CopyFromScreen(x, y, 0, 0, new Size(XX, YY));

       b.Save(@"C:\Applications\CaptureImage000.jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);

       /* Run 3 line below will lead to question 1 - through exception
       Bitmap bm = new Bitmap(@"C:\Applications\CaptureImage000.jpg");
       int black_pixels = CountPixels(b, Color.FromArgb(255, 0, 0, 0));
       textBox3.Text = black_pixels + " black pixels";
       */

       return b;
   }
   private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)// Do screen cap
   {
       Bitmap bmp = null;
       bmp = CapturedImage(X0, Y0);
   }
   ```

Comment: Please provide complete exception message.

Comment: Saving as jpg and comparing for 100% color equality do not go well together. save as png and consider adding some slack in the comparison. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27374550/how-to-compare-color-object-and-get-closest-color-in-an-color/27375621#27375621) for a discussion of color distance!

Comment: As for the questions: They are hard to understand. What is the error message? Why calculate the number if you only want to find one spot? What about the 'long' string? (Itought to be in a string variable `string path ..`, but otherwise it isn't long. Do you really want to save the bitmap or just scan it? Put it in a form level variable then! For even better speed you may want to look into Lockbits..

Comment: @TaW i just want to scan if there is any black color or close to black

Comment: Hi @user10035542 I can add a threshold to my answer to allow you to find 'close to black' pixels also if it suits. I believe I have solved the speed issues and the Exception looks to be just because the file already exists. Take a look at my solution below for more info. Hope that helps.

Comment: @user10035542 I've added the tolerance percent option to my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[EDIT] Worked on this tonight with OP, made some improvements
This now accounts for endianness of the machine and correctly compares colors by converting them to integers with the Color.ToArgb() function

the below code will work, I have added comments for clarity and given you some options. I wrote the code without an IDE but I am confident it is fine.

In both cases below, just keep the handle to the bitmap, don't need to save and reopen regardless of if you need a copy.

### Exception issue and improvements to CapturedImage function

**option A (recommended)**

Don't save the bitmap, you already have a handle, the graphics object just modified the BMP. Just leave the below code as is for this function and it will work fine without un-commenting one of the other options.

Code and other options:

```
    private Bitmap CapturedImage(Bitmap bm, int x, int y)
    {
        Bitmap b = new Bitmap(XX, YY);

        Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(b);
        g.CopyFromScreen(x, y, 0, 0, new Size(XX, YY));


        //option B - If you DO need to keep a copy of the image use PNG and delete the old image
        /*
        try
        {
            if(System.IO.File.Exists(@"C:\Applications\CaptureImage.png"))
            {
                System.IO.File.Delete(@"C:\Applications\CaptureImage.png");
            }
            b.Save(@"C:\Applications\CaptureImage.png", ImageFormat.Png);
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("There was a problem trying to save the image, is the file in open in another program?\r\nError:\r\n\r\n" + ex.Message);
        }
        */

        //option C - If you DO need to keep a copy of the image AND keep all copies of all images when you click the button use PNG and generate unique filename
        /*
        int id = 0;
        while(System.IO.File.Exists(@"C:\Applications\CaptureImage" + id.ToString().PadLeft('0',4) + ".png"))
        {
            //increment the id until a unique file name is found
            id++;
        }
        b.Save(@"C:\Applications\CaptureImage" + id.ToString().PadLeft('0',4) + ".png", ImageFormat.Png);
        */


        int black_pixels = CountPixels(b, Color.FromArgb(255, 0, 0, 0));
        textBox3.Text = black_pixels + " black pixels";

        return b;
    }
```

Now for the CountPixels function, you have 3 options but really, you have one really solid option, so I am omitting the others.

This locks the bits in the BMP, uses marshalling to copy the data into an array and scans the array for data, very, very fast, and you will likely not even need to remove the count. If you do STILL want to remove the count, just add "return 1;" right underneath where it increments the matches variable.

### Speed issue and improvements to CountPixels function

```
    private int CountPixels(Bitmap bm, Color target_color)
    {
        int matches = 0;
        Bitmap bmp = (Bitmap)bm.Clone();
        BitmapData bmpDat = bmp.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height), ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, bmp.PixelFormat);
        int size = bmpDat.Stride * bmpDat.Height;
        byte[] subPx = new byte[size];
        System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(bmpDat.Scan0, subPx, 0, size);

        //change the 4 (ARGB) to a 3 (RGB) if you don't have an alpha channel, this is for 32bpp images

        //ternary operator to check endianess of machine and organise pixel colors as A,R,G,B or B,G,R,A (little endian is reversed);
        Color temp = BitConverter.IsLittleEndian ? Color.FromArgb(subPx[i + 2], subPx[i + 1], subPx[i]) : Color.FromArgb(subPx[i + 1], subPx[i + 2], subPx[i + 3]);
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i += 4 ) //4 bytes per pixel A, R, G, B
        {
            if(temp.ToArgb() == target_color.ToArgb())
            {
                matches++;
            }
        }
        System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(subPx, 0, bmpDat.Scan0, subPx.Length);
        bmp.UnlockBits(bmpDat);

        return matches;
    }
```

### Finally the same function but allowing for a tolerance percent

```
    private int CountPixels(Bitmap bm, Color target_color, float tolerancePercent)
    {
        int matches = 0;
        Bitmap bmp = (Bitmap)bm.Clone();
        BitmapData bmpDat = bmp.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height), ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, bmp.PixelFormat);
        int size = bmpDat.Stride * bmpDat.Height;
        byte[] subPx = new byte[size];
        System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(bmpDat.Scan0, subPx, 0, size);

        for (int i = 0; i < size; i += 4 )
        {
            byte r = BitConverter.IsLittleEndian ? subPx[i+2] : subPx[i+3];
            byte g = BitConverter.IsLittleEndian ? subPx[i+1] : subPx[i+2];
            byte b = BitConverter.IsLittleEndian ? subPx[i] : subPx[i+1];
            float distancePercent = (float)Math.Sqrt(
                Math.Abs(target_color.R-r) + 
                Math.Abs(target_color.G-g) + 
                Math.Abs(target_color.B-b)
            ) / 7.65f;

            if(distancePercent < tolerancePercent)
            {
                matches++;
            }
        }
        System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(subPx, 0, bmpDat.Scan0, subPx.Length);
        bmp.UnlockBits(bmpDat);

        return matches;
    }
```

Comment: About the line: Bitmap bmp = bm.Clone(); Error: Can not implicitly convert type "object" to "System.Drawing.Bitmap".

Comment: It should just be a cast.

e.g. Bitmap bmp = (Bitmap)bm.Clone();

But I will correct this and check the code in IDE

Comment: I will need more time to understand your code as i am not expert about C# and programming. I learn C# myself and having trouble about it,... Can you please give me some guide to learn c#... if possible, can u be my master =DDDD ???

Comment: Heads up, I fixed the 2 missing casts in the CountPixels (threshold function) and the "new Color(" that was supposed to be "Color.FromArgb(" in the normal CountPixels function

Keep it up, the language is super fun and more flexible than you realise. The best way to learn is to find something you want to achieve, give it a shot, fail or succeed and keep trying.

I don't know why people down-voted your question, I could see you put a good amount of effort in, and I barely had to change anything to get it working.

You will have this down in no time.

Comment: thanks for your valuable help, this problem take me 7 day from morning to late night! My goal is learning c# through making a program to play favorite web game automatically and some other sofware. I'm planning on developing this project for more than a few month and release it for community. I also learning about artificial neural networks and AI so programming skill is needed. I'm very interested in you after read your profile, and almost same thinking as your. is it possible for us to become friends?

Comment: Always happy to chat. I've added my contact details to profile, feel free to get in touch on Discord.