# Setting/Matching colors in C#

Tags: c#, graphics, colors, rgb

I have some colors that belongs to clothes that I wanna find the set of those colors (find matching colors).

For example we know that we can use Red with Orange , or Black with Red (even in real life).

But the problem is how to find these matching colors programmatically in C#.

A way i found my self is find the specific color parents (primary color / base color).
for example Orange parents are Yellow and Red (if you mix Red and Yellow ,the result is Orange) and then the matching colors are all colors between the parents (Red and Yellow).

But also I don't know how to do that as well.

I would be thankful for your help.

Thanks in advance .

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27374550/how-to-compare-color-object-and-get-closest-color-in-an-color

Comment: I would consider this an overly broad question since it does not specify how you actually want the color matching to work, and the topic may have more to do with graphical design than programming unless you narrow the problem a bit. I would recommend taking a look at the HSV or HSL color formats. These are more human-friendly representations that may make the problem easier.

Comment: @JonasH after googling a lot and reading a huge amount of articles , i think as you say there no way but working  with HSV or HSL . anyway thanks ;) .